# Error when trying to install library permanently on google colab

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to install library permanently on google colab. So I run this code first:

```
import os, sys
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount = True)

my_path = '/content/notebooks'
os.symlink('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/my_env', my_path)
sys.path.insert(0, my_path)
```

there's no error running above code.

However, when I run the code below, I got the error:

`!pip install --target=$my_path jdc`

```
Collecting jdc
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/cb/9afea749985eef20f3160e8826a531c7502e40c35a038dfe49b67726e9a0/jdc-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: jdc
Successfully installed jdc-0.0.9
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 550, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-target-21y8mx4d/lib/python/jdc' -> '/content/notebooks/jdc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 505, in run
    options.target_dir, target_temp_dir, options.upgrade
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 563, in _handle_target_dir
    target_item_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 561, in move
    symlinks=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 321, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/notebooks/jdc'
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First target your directory where you want to install the library like this:

`%cd "/path/to/your/directory"`

Then install using ```pip``:

`pip install jdc`